# C# clean minimal api where to add the features?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, fast-endpoints

iam looking into the clean minimal api from Nick Chapsas => https://github.com/Elfocrash/clean-minimal-api.

I find this structure very cool and i want to use this as a boilerplate for my next project.

But he has only implemented Customers.
I want this API stuct with more than only Customers something like Games, Consoles, Users.
What is the correct struct to implement this?

What i have to put in the Feature folder?

What is the struct with more than one feature?

I need a clean struct.

Maybe you know what i mean or maybe you can give me a better .net7 boilerplate?

Thank you!

[What about this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLv7h.png)

Asking for structure

Comment: Feel free to structure it however it makes sense to you. How you structure it is  very opinion based, there's no one right answer.

Comment: yeah like mason said, there's really no one-size-fits all structure. if you follow vertical slice architecture and keep your slices totally isolated, you can easily move features around without breaking anything. [see here](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/building-rest-apis-in-net-6-the-easy-way-3h0d) for an introductory article on the matter.

Answer (score 1):

In the project you sent, there is no folder named Feature and it is well structured for a small project, but if you want to develop it into a larger one in the future, you will have to export the models, services, data provider and etc.